# Angular 11 post request for a pdf to .Net Core backend

Tags: angular, pdf, http-post, blob, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to send html, as part of a post request to a .NET Core web api, to be converted to a pdf on the server and receive this file on the client. I can't get the request/response methods right as I either get a 415 or 400 responses or parsing error on the client.
In Angular I have

```
   this.apiService
      .generatePdf((this.diagram.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).innerHTML)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });

generatePdf(html: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.urls.document}/html2pdf`,
      { html },
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      }
    );
```

and on the backend the method is

```
[HttpPost("html2pdf")]
public FileResult Html2Pdf([FromBody] string html)
{
   HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   var stream = repository.Html2Pdf(html);
   return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

EDIT: my latest effort which results in a 400 error is this

```
this.apiService
      .generatePdf((this.diagram.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).innerHTML)
      .subscribe(
        (blob) => {
          downloadFile(blob, 'diagram.pdf');
        }
          );
  generatePdf(html: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.post<Blob>(
      `${this.urls.document}/html2pdf`,
      { html },
      { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }
    );
  }
```

and on the server

```
[HttpPost("html2pdf")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Html2Pdf([FromBody] string html)
        {            
            var bytes = await repository.Html2Pdf(html);
            return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993193/post-with-int-string-simple-type-in-body-to-asp-net-core-web-api-2-1-not-worki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backend

```
[HttpPost("html2pdf")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Html2Pdf([FromBody] DocumentConvertRequest model)
{            
    var bytes = await repository.Html2Pdf(model.Html);
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Frontend

```
generatePdf(html: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(
      `${this.urls.document}/html2pdf`,
      JSON.stringify({ html }),
      {
        headers: this.headers,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      }
    );
  }

this.apiService
  .generatePdf((this.diagram.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).innerHTML)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {          
      const newBlob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = data;
      link.download = 'diagram.pdf';
      link.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('click', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          view: window
        })
      );

      setTimeout(function () {            
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
        link.remove();
      }, 0);
    }
  );
```